# WooСommerce. Как сделать выбор разных цветов товара?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять как реализован выбор нескольких вариаций товара, меняется зависимости от выбраного количества. Вот [пример как работает](https://vigoshop.pl/produkt/zegarek-smart-wodoodporny-z-kolorowym-ekranem-dotykowym-hd-ulti-d-32/)
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вынужден вас огорчить, но нет такого в стандартной вуке)

Comment: Может какой-то плагин?